# Code on finding non-dominated points not working properly

Tags: c, gdb, dynamic-arrays

I am a beginner at programming (and it is not my subject of discipline) and this is my first question here, apologies if I'm not posting it it properly.

I am trying a problem (in C) in which one has to define a structure for a point, take inputs of points from a file to a dynamic array, in which the first line contains the number of points, and the remaining lines contain the coordinates of the points with spaces in between. Then I have to write a function to determine the points which are non-dominated, definitions given :

> • A point P1 = ( x1 , y1 ) is dominated by a point P2 = ( x2 , y2 ) if
>   y2 > y1 and x2 > x1
>
> • A point is non-dominated in a set of points, if no point dominates
>   it in that set

And another function to determine and print the level of dominance of each point stored in the array formed. I need to print all non-dominated points, and then print level of dominance of all the points.

This is the code that I have written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 20
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

typedef struct Coordinates{
    float xcord;
    float ycord;
}POINT;

//globally declaring dynamic array of points
POINT *Array_of_Points;
//globally declaring dynamic array of non-dominated points
POINT *Non_dominated;

//declaring some functions
int dominance(int n);
int Read_File(char filename[]);
void Xmerge(int head, int middle, int tail);
void XmergeSort(int head, int tail);
void level_of_dominance(int a);

int main(){
    char Arr[MAX];
    int n, i, d;
    printf("Enter file name...");
    scanf("%s", Arr);
    n = Read_File(Arr);
    if(!Read_File(Arr)){    //if error occurs
            printf("Terminating program with exit code -1\n");
        return -1;   //terminate program with return value -1
    }
    //finds non-dominated points and prints them
    d = dominance(n);
    printf("The non dominated points are:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < d; i++){
        printf("(%f, %f)", Non_dominated[i].xcord, Non_dominated[i].ycord);
    }
    //print all points with levels of dominance
    level_of_dominance(n);
    printf("End of program... Terminating with exit code 0\n");
    free(Array_of_Points);
    free(Non_dominated);
    return 0;
}

//function reads file in required manner
int Read_File(char filename[]){
    int n;  //to store number of points present in file
    int count = 0;
    float x, y;
    FILE *fptr = fopen(filename, "r");  //opening given file in readable format
    if(!fptr)   //file handling if pointer returns null
    {
        printf("The file %s can't be opened.\n", filename);
        return FALSE;
    }
    fscanf(fptr, "%d", &n); //reading first line consisting of number of points
    Array_of_Points = (POINT*)malloc(n * sizeof(POINT));  //allocating memory for npoints
    //reading points from file and storing them in globally created dynamic array
    while((count < n) && (fscanf(fptr, "%f", &x) == TRUE && fscanf(fptr, "%f", &y) == TRUE)){
        Array_of_Points[count].xcord = x;
        Array_of_Points[count].ycord = y;
        ++count;
    }
    return n;   //returns number of points
}

int dominance(int n){   //returns number of non-dominated points
    /*METHOD TO FIND DOMINANCE:
    * First, arranging points in array by sorting, say, x co-ordinates in DESCENDING ORDER...
    * using merge sort algorithm for the same
    * The first point in this sorted array is automatically a non dominated point,
    * as no other point has x coordinate greater than it
    * Then, traverse sorted array and keep track of largest y value, initializing first one to max
    * While traversing, the point with y value grater than y max is also non dominated,
    * and contributes to new y max and so on...
    **/

    int foo = 0;  //keeps track of number of non-dominated points found so far, initialized to zero
    int i = 0;
    XmergeSort(0, n);
    int ymax = Array_of_Points[0].ycord;
    //add first element of the array to Non_dominated array and increase foo count
    Non_dominated = (POINT*)malloc(sizeof(POINT));
    Non_dominated[0] = Array_of_Points[0];
    ++foo;
    for(; foo < n; foo++){
        if(Array_of_Points[foo].ycord > ymax){
            ++i;
            Non_dominated = (POINT*)realloc(Non_dominated, (i + 1) * sizeof(POINT));
            Non_dominated[i] = Array_of_Points[foo];
        }
    }
    //all non dominated points stored in array
    return i;
}

void level_of_dominance(int a){   //returns number of points dominating a point
    int i, j, flag = 0;
    for(i = a - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        for(j = i; j >= 0; j--){
            if((Array_of_Points[i].xcord <= Array_of_Points[j].xcord)&&(Array_of_Points[i].ycord <= Array_of_Points[j].ycord)){
                ++flag;
            }
        }
        printf("(%f, %f) is dominated by %d points.\n", Array_of_Points[i].xcord, Array_of_Points[i].ycord, flag);
        flag = 0;   //resetting number of points for next point
    }
}

void XmergeSort(int head, int tail){
    int mid;
    if(head < tail){
        mid = (head +tail)/2;
        XmergeSort(head, mid);
        XmergeSort(mid + 1, tail);

        Xmerge(head, mid, tail);
    }
}

//function to merge 2 halves of array
void Xmerge(int l, int m, int r)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 =  r - m;

    /* create temp arrays */
    POINT *T1, *T2;
    T1 = (POINT*)malloc(n1 * sizeof(POINT));
    T2 = (POINT*)malloc(n2 * sizeof(POINT));

    /* Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] */
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        T1[i] = Array_of_Points[l + i];
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        T2[j] = Array_of_Points[m + 1+ j];

    /* Merge the temp arrays back into arr[l..r]*/
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = l;
    while (i < n1 && j < n2)
    {
        Array_of_Points[k] = ((T1[i].xcord <= T2[j].xcord)?T1[i]:T2[j]);
        ((T1[i].xcord <= T2[j].xcord)?i++:j++);
        k++;
    }

    /* Copy the remaining elements of L[], if there are any */
    while (i < n1)
    {
        Array_of_Points[k] = T1[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    /* Copy the remaining elements of R[], if there are any */
    while (j < n2)
    {
        Array_of_Points[k] = T2[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}
```

While running this code on online gdb, I am getting a segmentation fault, like this:

> Reading symbols from a.out...done.
>   /usr/share/gdb/gdbinit: No such file or directory.
>   (gdb) run
>   Starting program: /home/a.out
>   Enter file name...inp.dat
>   Testing... no. of non dominated points = 4
>   The non dominated points are:
>   Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x0000000000400b82 in level_of_dominance (a=5) at main.c:107
>   107                 if((Array_of_Points[i].xcord <= Array_of_Points[j].xcord)&&(Ar
>   ray_of_Points[i].ycord <= Array_of_Points[j].ycord)){
>   (gdb)

The coordinates of non-dominated points aren't being printed here either.
I'm sorry if what I'm asking is stupid, but I hope someone can help me understand what went wrong. 
Thanks in advance.

P.S Please let me know if I should edit my question.

EDIT: I had made a bad mistake in line 105 of the code, as pointed out by @JGroven where in place of j--, I had written j++. I have corrected the same above, but my code isn't doing what it should. This is what the debugger is showing:

> Reading symbols from a.out...done.
>   /usr/share/gdb/gdbinit: No such file or directory.
>   (gdb) run
>   Starting program: /home/a.out
>   Enter file name...inp.dat
>   The non dominated points are:
>   (0.000000, 0.000000)(2.500000, 7.200000)(4.700000, 5.000000)(5.600000, 9.500000)(9
>   .000000, 5.900000) is dominated by 0 points.
>   (5.600000, 9.500000) is dominated by 0 points.
>   (4.700000, 5.000000) is dominated by 0 points.
>   (2.500000, 7.200000) is dominated by 0 points.
>   (0.000000, 0.000000) is dominated by 0 points.
>   End of program... Terminating with exit code 0
>   *** Error in `/home/a.out': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000006034c0 *
>   **
>
> Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
>   0x00007ffff7a47c37 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
>
> ```
> at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56                                  56      ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or
> ```
>
> directory.        (gdb)

EDIT 2: As further pointed out by @Hitokiri,j will become -1 if initialized to i - 1, hence I have changed that to i. And also changed the type of the function to find level of dominance into void.

Comment: Check if your array indexes are not out of bounds in line 107

Comment: Show a minimal `inp.dat` that triggers the problem.

Comment: `for(j = i - 1; j >= 0; j++)` looks wrong to me.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thank you for your prompt response. The data to be input in the inp.dat file has been provided as follows:                                                                         5
2.5 7.2
4.7 5
9 5.9
5.6 9.5
12.6 2.3

Comment: @JGroven Ok, thank you, I shall check the same

Comment: @JGroven Sorry. bad mistake there. it should have been --, not ++

Comment: @Struppi20 please [edit] your question instead of posting in a comment.

Comment: @Struppi20 please, show the expected output

Comment: @Hitokiri I have figured out my mistake. There's something wrong with the merge sort function which I'll check shortly, for the time being I have used insertion sort, and as a friend pointed out, the function "dominance" also needed some changes. I am adding an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my mistake with the help of a friend. The dominance function wasn't completely correct, I have made changes there. And there is something not working properly with the merge sort function I have written, which I shall try to figure out shortly. In the meantime I have replaced it with insertion sort. I am posting my corrected code below.

Thanks to everyone for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 20
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

//segmentation fault...

typedef struct Coordinates{
    float xcord;
    float ycord;
}POINT;

//globally declaring dynamic array of points
POINT *Array_of_Points;
//globally declaring dynamic array of non-dominated points
POINT *Non_dominated;

//declaring some functions
int dominance(int n);
int Read_File(char filename[]);
/*void Xmerge(int head, int middle, int tail);
void XmergeSort(int);*/
void XInsertion(int n);
int level_of_dominance(int a);

int main(){
    char Arr[MAX];
    int n, i, d;
    printf("Enter file name...");
    scanf("%s", Arr);
    n = Read_File(Arr);
    if(!Read_File(Arr)){    //if error occurs
            printf("Terminating program with exit code -1\n");
        return -1;   //terminate program with return value -1
    }
    //finds non-dominated points and prints them
    d = dominance(n);
    printf("The non dominated points are:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < d; i++){
        printf("(%f, %f)", Non_dominated[i].xcord, Non_dominated[i].ycord);
    }
    printf("\n");
    //print all points with levels of dominance
    level_of_dominance(n);
    printf("End of program... Terminating with exit code 0\n");
    free(Array_of_Points);
    free(Non_dominated);
    return 0;
}

//function reads file in required manner
int Read_File(char filename[]){
    int n;  //to store number of points present in file
    int count = 0;
    float x, y;
    FILE *fptr = fopen(filename, "r");  //opening given file in readable format
    if(!fptr)   //file handling if pointer returns null
    {
        printf("The file %s can't be opened.\n", filename);
        return FALSE;
    }
    fscanf(fptr, "%d", &n); //reading first line consisting of number of points
    Array_of_Points = (POINT*)malloc(n * sizeof(POINT));  //allocating memory to store data of n points
    //reading points from file and storing them in globally created dynamic array
    while((count < n) && (fscanf(fptr, "%f", &x) == TRUE && fscanf(fptr, "%f", &y) == TRUE)){
        Array_of_Points[count].xcord = x;
        Array_of_Points[count].ycord = y;
        ++count;
    }
    return n;   //returns number of points
}

int dominance(int n){   //returns number of non-dominated points
    /*METHOD TO FIND DOMINANCE:
    * First, arranging points in array by sorting, say, x co-ordinates in DESCENDING ORDER...
    * using merge sort algorithm for the same
    * The first point in this sorted array is automatically a non dominated point,
    * as no other point has x coordinate greater than it
    * Then, traverse sorted array and keep track of largest y value, initializing first one to max
    * While traversing, the point with y value grater than y max is also non dominated,
    * and contributes to new y max and so on...
    **/

    int foo = 0;  //keeps track of number of non-dominated points found so far, initialized to zero
    int i;
    XInsertion(n);
    int ymax = Array_of_Points[0].ycord;
    //add first element of the array to Non_dominated array and increase foo count
    Non_dominated = (POINT*)malloc(sizeof(POINT));
    Non_dominated[0] = Array_of_Points[0];
    ++foo;
    for(i=1 ; i < n; i++){  //note change
        if(Array_of_Points[i].ycord > ymax){
            ymax=Array_of_Points[i].ycord; /*changes made*/
            Non_dominated = (POINT*)realloc(Non_dominated, (foo+1) * sizeof(POINT));
            Non_dominated[foo] = Array_of_Points[i];
            foo++;
        }
    }
    //all non dominated points stored in array
    return foo;
}

int level_of_dominance(int a){   //returns number of points dominating a point
    int i, j, flag = 0;
    for(i = a - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        for(j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--){
            if((Array_of_Points[i].xcord <= Array_of_Points[j].xcord)&&(Array_of_Points[i].ycord <= Array_of_Points[j].ycord)){
                ++flag;
            }
        }
        printf("(%f, %f) is dominated by %d points.\n", Array_of_Points[i].xcord, Array_of_Points[i].ycord, flag);
        flag = 0;   //resetting number of points for next point
    }
}
/*
void XmergeSort(int head, int tail){
    int mid;
    if(head < tail){
        mid = (head +tail)/2;
        XmergeSort(head, mid);
        XmergeSort(mid + 1, tail);

        Xmerge(head, mid, tail);
    }
}

//function to merge 2 halves of array
void Xmerge(int l, int m, int r)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 =  r - m;

    // create temp arrays
    POINT *T1, *T2;
    T1 = (POINT*)malloc(n1 * sizeof(POINT));
    T2 = (POINT*)malloc(n2 * sizeof(POINT));

    // Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[]
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        T1[i] = Array_of_Points[l + i];
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        T2[j] = Array_of_Points[m + 1+ j];

    // Merge the temp arrays back into arr[l..r]
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = l;
    while (i < n1 && j < n2)
    {
        Array_of_Points[k] = ((T1[i].xcord <= T2[j].xcord)?T1[i]:T2[j]);
        ((T1[i].xcord <= T2[j].xcord)?i++:j++);
        k++;
    }

    // Copy the remaining elements of L[], if there are any
    while (i < n1)
    {
        Array_of_Points[k] = T1[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    // Copy the remaining elements of R[], if there are any
    while (j < n2)
    {
        Array_of_Points[k] = T2[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}*/
void XInsertion(int n)
{
    int i,j;
    POINT a;
//Applying insertion-sort on x co-ordinates to have them arranged in decreasing order
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        j=i-1;
        a=Array_of_Points[i];
        while((Array_of_Points[j].xcord<=a.xcord)&&(j>=0))
        {
            if(Array_of_Points[j].xcord==a.xcord && Array_of_Points[j].ycord>a.ycord)
                break;//in case of tie, arrange in decreasing order
            else
            {
                Array_of_Points[j+1]=Array_of_Points[j];
                j--;
            }
        }
        Array_of_Points[j+1]=a;
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

> Enter file name...inp.dat
>   The non dominated points are:
>   (12.600000, 2.300000)(9.000000, 5.900000)(5.600000, 9.500000)
>   (2.500000, 7.200000) is dominated by 1 points.
>   (4.700000, 5.000000) is dominated by 2 points.
>   (5.600000, 9.500000) is dominated by 0 points.
>   (9.000000, 5.900000) is dominated by 0 points.
>   (12.600000, 2.300000) is dominated by 0 points.
>   End of program... Terminating with exit code 0

Any suggestions and tips to improve my program and techniques for debugging are most welcome.